# Angular4, Getting error f.ngOnChanges is not a function in target es5

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

Getting an error

> f.ngOnChanges is not a function

The issue only happens if my tsconfig.json file is setup to target es5, However if my target is es6 everything works as expected.

Does anyone know how I can get ngOnChange work if my target is es5?

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Type, Input, Output, OnInit,OnChanges, ElementRef, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
       selector: "form",
        styleUrls:['./crop.form.component.css'],
      templateUrl: './crop.form.component.html',
      })


export class CropFormComponent extends Type   {


@Input() imageFile: any;  
@Output() showUploadModal = new EventEmitter;



size: string;


// imageCropped: boolean; // imageNotCropped: boolean;



    //Cropper 2 data
    data:any;


    constructor() { }


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void{


}

}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `OnChanges` interface to use that method:

```
export class CropFormComponent extends Type implements OnChanges { ... }
```

More about this in the docs:

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: Good point but it did not work. I still get the same error message.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I guess it could be connected to the `Type` super class, why do you have it there?

Comment: Btw according to the docs, `Type` is interface, so you should use it via `implements`, not `extends`.

Comment: I have a Type because I have a superclass which I need to use.  And type only works with  extends.